# Sliding stacked grid items with Bootstrap / JQuery / Media Query

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this one, but I know it can be done. I have a site built with Twitter's Bootstrap, and I'm following the grid layout. Problem is, I have several different sized columns. I want them to slide instead of stack when viewed on a mobile device.

Right now:

```
A   B
A B C
A
```

On a mobile:

```
A
B
A
B
C
A
```

Ideally, that first would have a carousel effect or a JQuery slider containing both A and B, with a nice snapping animation. I could add a carousel and then add to the JS "if (widowWidth<768)" to only load all these sliders on mobile. I can then write the media queries to make them not stack, but I am a bit lost on how to actually go about doing that dynamically and putting it all together. I know how to make a single row do what I'd like with two copies of the content, hiding one, and showing the other as a slider, but that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: good question, first idea would be to add both elements (grid and carousels) and hide one of them with rules in mediaqueries, not sure it's a good way to proceed. I'm following your question to see upcoming answers :)

Comment: Perhaps you could show a jsfiddle or live version of the site so we can have a look?

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle showing the current behavior on the top, and the desired behavior on mobile on the bottom. Does this make sense?

http://jsfiddle.net/wySCH/1/